# Multiple AND or OR operators in Eclipse smarthome rule using rule REST API

Tags: eclipse, rest, operators, rule

I'm consuming Eclipse smart home REST API to create rules. I already know how to create a rule with only one condition.

```
    "conditions": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "label": "Test rule",
            "description": "This triggers the rule if an item state has changed.",
            "configuration": {
            "itemName": "sensor_luminance_TUID_zwave_device_octopuszstick1_node12",
            "state": "48",
            "operator": "="
            },
            "type": "core.ItemStateCondition"
        }
    ]
```

But I have a requirement to create rules with multiple OR or AND operators. 
Ex:

```
    If( X AND Y AND Z ) {
       DO THIS
    }

    If ((X AND Y) OR Z) {
       DO THIS
    }
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in Eclipse community forum and got the answer.

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1090481&goto=1778152&#msg_1778152

> Hi Dushan,
>
> a rule can have a list of triggers and can be started by any of the
> triggers in this list. As for the conditions, a rule will execute its
> action(s) only if all given conditions match. For more information
> start on the JavaDoc for the Rule class.
>
> Hope that helps.
>
> Cheers, Henning

Hope this will help somebody in future.